# Alarm Manager and Pending Intent Cancel Not Working

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

**I schedule Alarm from Activity like.**

```
   private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;  
            mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) ACT_ActiveSession.getAppContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LocalNotification.class);
            intent.putExtra("alertBody", "");
            intent.putExtra(K.SESSIONID, "");
            intent.putExtra("TIME", "");
            intent.putExtra("BATCHNO","");
            intent.putExtra("REQUEST_CODE", "");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    ACT_ActiveSession.getAppContext(), REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
            mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, finishTime,
                    pendingIntent);
            // alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, finishTime,
            // (1 * 1000), pendingIntent);
```

`intent.putExtra("","");` only used for some task on `BroadcastReceiver`

**And Cancel Alarm From   Fragment**

```
private AlarmManager mAlarmManager; 

    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) mActivity
                            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    Intent updateServiceIntent = new Intent(mActivity,
                            ACT_Home.class);

                    PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                            mActivity, REQUEST_CODE,
                            updateServiceIntent, 0);
                     pendingUpdateIntent.cancel();
                    // Cancel alarms
                    if (pendingUpdateIntent != null) {
                        mAlarmManager.cancel(pendingUpdateIntent);
                        Log.e("", "alaram canceled ");
                    } else {
                        Log.e("", "pendingUpdateIntent is null");
                    }
```

But Alarm Manager is not cancelled.
Here i change `mActivity` = `MyActivity`'s static `getApplicationContext();` and also change different Flags and different Context.

Also I refer many answer. **But doesn't work any code.** [Link1](http://itquestionz.com/questions/4586489/android-alarmmanager-cancel-from-another-activity) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615986/how-to-stop-an-alarm-in-android/17616299#17616299) [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106299/change-the-intent-of-pendingintent-which-is-used-by-an-alarmmanager/14244012#14244012)

please give me solution as soon as possible.
and apologize for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the alarm using this `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LocalNotification.class);
```

But you try to cancel it using this `Intent`:

```
Intent updateServiceIntent = new Intent(mActivity, ACT_Home.class);
```

These `Intent`s do not match, so the cancel does nothing. If you want to cancel the alarm you need to use an `Intent` in the cancel call that matches the `Intent` you used to schedule the alarm.