# Is it possible to change AlarmManager's Intent every time it fires?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Is it possible to change the `Intent` and it's extras each time `AlarmManager` is triggered?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106299/change-the-intent-of-pendingintent-which-is-used-by-an-alarmmanager check this out

Comment: Tried the FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT still didn't work. 

My goal is to just change the extras, no need for actions.

Comment: My I supposed to call the AlarmManager method each time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
// Extras aren't used to find the PendingIntent
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, tag, i,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE); // find the old PendingIntent
if (pi != null) {
    // Now cancel the alarm that matches the old PendingIntent
    am.cancel(pi);
}
// Now create and schedule a new Alarm
i = new Intent(context, NewAlarm.class); // New component for alarm
i.putExtra("position", tag); // Whatever new extras
pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, tag, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
// Reschedule the alarm
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+ time, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
```

Yes everytime you need to cancel the current one and launch the new one if you want to make any changes in Intent like data extras, action , component anything.

Comment: Will this run the new intent once it is fired, or do I need to call the method again ?

Comment: How do I call the method as soon as the alarm fires ?

Comment: When you have to cancel the previous one so definitely you need to give call to method again to create new one. When you are firing alarm in that part of code give call to function. Try this hope it would help I am not much sure about this